# wpf how can I create a perfectly measured trapezoid button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a trapezoid-shaped button in Blends using my mouse. A markup has been generated but I am not a geometry guy so if you could pin point to me which values should I change to make it a perfectly-shaped trapezoid.

here is the markup:

```
<Path Data="M14,0.5 L60.5,0.5 74.5,29.5 0.5,29.5 z"  Height="30" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Width="75"/>
```

What does "M14" and "L60" and "z" stands for,  btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M` specifies the start point of the path, and each pair of coordinates after `L` specifies a line path. `z` specifies the end of the path. For more information, see [Path Markup Syntax on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

To align your path precisely, it should look like:

```
<Path Data="M15,0 L60,0 75,30 0,30 z" Height="30" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Width="75"/>
```

Your original path is off by 1 to 0.5 for each coordinate.

Here is the original path (in red) behind the corrected path:

[image: https://i.pyratron.com/OGBFHL.png]