# WPF TabControl show tabs only no content

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

The idea is to simply use the tabs (headers) to make a selection. So the "content" is unnecessary. And I can't seem to find an easy way to make the content "empty" or take up zero height.

So visually, you should only be presented with tabs, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you customise the `ControlTemplate` from the MSDN example and remove the selected content: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137(v=vs.90).aspx

So it would become something like this:

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TabPanel 
            Name="HeaderPanel"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Panel.ZIndex="1" 
            Margin="0,0,4,-1" 
            IsItemsHost="True"
            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
            Background="Transparent" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: If using this style on a control that extends TabControl, with DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata. You can remove the line "<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />" as this will cause a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 2):

To hide the content of the tabs you can override the ContentTemplate of the TabControl.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
         <DataTemplate/>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I am still left with a thin panel below the tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can use overlapped tab shaped buttons, you do not really need a tab control.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532063) is how to create custom shaped buttons in WPF.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678384) is how to create a tab shaped button.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking to reuse TabControl. I've also been looking at RadioButton styled with ToggleButtons.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to pull this off:

```
<TabControl Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```